# L-BFGS-B. Forces early stop with no 0 gradient

Tags: python, optimization, linear, nonlinear, scipy

I am minimizing a non-linear function which is close to linear with L-BFGS-B with scipy.optimize. The issue is that I have a non zero jacobian, low levels of tolerance but the algorithm keeps early stopping. I've tried:

1. Lower gtol
2. Lower ftol
3. Increase eps

To give you an example this is what happens in the input parameters (x in f(x)) in each iteration.

The algorithm minimizes the function but the last 2 iterations, tries the exact same x therefore the function output is the same and terminates "successfully"

[image: Parameters_in_each_iteration]

However, the jacobian is positive and far away from the tolerance levels

[image]

To give you a little bit more flavor to what happens to the target function:

[image: target_function]

My question is, how come the algorithm terminates early when there is some progress that can be made given the Jacobian? Why does it evaluate 2 times the function in with the same x parameters, understand that ftol is fulfilled and terminates? Why doesn't it try new params given the Jacobian?

Thanks for your help